# Using AD for Authentication and Asp.Net Identity for Authorization

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, authorization, asp.net-identity-2

I am quite confused about one requirement that i've received and how to correctly fullfill it...i hope that someone can help me figure out something.

I have to add Authentication/Authorization to an existing MVC 5 intranet application that will be used only by the customer's intranet users. This web app hosts an AngularJs application that uses a set of WebApi (hosted inside the same intranet and used only for intranet purposes).

The application will be used by different kind of users that can have different grants (e.g: can create things, can modify things, can delete things) and those grants must be declined for different Countries (consider the Country as, conceptually, a subsite). So a User can be the "administrator" (considering the administrator as a User with all grants) for the France, but be a simple user for Germany and not authorized at all for the other countries.

The requirement is to use AD for Authentication, but not for Authorization purposes.

I am not an expert of security and i did some research to try to understand the possible solutions. The most important thing i have understood is to separate the Authentication from the Authorization.
From a simple Authentication point of view, it's easy to use AD (or Windows Auth).

What i am missing is how to perform the Authorization part.

I have seen a lot of tutorials for ASP.Net Identity with Individual Accounts, all it's clear and easy, as it's using the UserManager to perform lookups on the db for the users to verify the authentication, and from there take the roles data(saving those info in a cookie).

I need to understand what should be the correct way to handle my scenario.

The user should log in using it's domain credentials, then i should receive a response from AD, if ok i should get the corresponding user from my db and retrieve its role data...correct?

If so, how could i perform those tasks. 
Is it a wrong way of solving the problem? 
And if so, how can i do that?
What is the best way to "pass" the auth/entication/orization token to the WebApi in order to secure them as well?
One last question...could it be possible to fulfill the requirements by using only AD (not relying on the db for grants)?

Sorry for the (most probably) dull questions but i'm feeling like i am missing some **VERY** key points.

Comment: Are the users intranet via vpn or are you talking about users that login via WWW?  Mix of both?